# Detect drag&Drop was start but not realized over tableView

Tags: macos, swift, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I have an application with one NSTableView and i can drag&drop some file on the table. If the user drag a file over the cells in my table, each cell becomes highlighted (i have implemented custom highlighting)

In detail it something about:

1. If the user drag the file over another cell, it becomes highlighted. The old cell becomes again normal
2. If user drop the file over a cell it becomes also again normal.

But the problem is if the user start dragging some file over the cells but drop somewhere outside application. The last highlighted cell remains in this state and I don't know how to catch this event.

Has somebody an idea? Preferably in swift

Edit:
There is this function to validate drop operations but it get only call if the drop is on the table `tableView(tableView: NSTableView, validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, proposedRow row: Int, proposedDropOperation dropOperation: NSTableViewDropOperation)`

Comment: Please attach demo app with some screenshots. It's not clear what you did or what you want (e.g. called registerForDraggedTypes) and read the basics of Drag&Drop https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html

Comment: @xhruso00 Like the titel and my question said I having a table. I can detect drop operations on the table but not outside the table or outside the application. The answer is realy easy I just need to subclass `NSTableView` and overide `draggingExited`. I post an answer if i have more time